# change url on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.custom-switch').click(function(){
        var url = jQuery('.anchr').attr('href');
        var src = jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-source');
        var type = jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-target');
        if(type == 'monthly'){
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('href', src);
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-source', url);
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-target', 'yearly');
        }else{
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('href', src);
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-source', url); 
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-target', 'monthly');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="switch"><span class="monthly">Billed Monthly</span> <div class="custom-switch" id="undefined"><input class="custom-switch" type="checkbox" id="custom-switch-0"><label for="custom-switch-0"></label></div> <span class="annually">Billed Annually (Save 10%) </span></div>


<ul><li class="plan__price"><a href="https://www.example.com/india/?amt=7499" data-source=https://www.example.com/india/?amt=6749" data-target="monthly" class="anchr btn btn-primary price-btn" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> Pay Now </a></li></ul>

<ul><li class="plan__price"><a href="https://www.example.com/india/?amt=7499" data-source=https://www.example.com/india/?amt=7749" data-target="monthly" class="anchr btn btn-primary price-btn" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Pay Now</a></li></ul>
```

i used tow pay now buttons with different urls, bothe button get the same url after toggle. need different urls , if i write again same code for the second button with different then working good

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.custom-switch').click(function(){
        var url = jQuery('.anchr').attr('href');
        var src = jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-source');
        var type = jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-target');
        if(type == 'monthly'){
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('href', src);
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-source', url);
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-target', 'yearly');
        }else{
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('href', src);
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-source', url); 
            jQuery('.anchr').attr('data-target', 'monthly');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did a few fixes to your code:

- Fixed your html so all quotes are correct.
- Changed the selector for the click handler to `input.custom-switch` because you had multiple of those classes in your html.
- Looped over `.anchr` to adjust both buttons.
- simplified the code inside the loop.

```js
jQuery('input.custom-switch').click(function() {
  jQuery('.anchr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.attr('href');
    var src = $this.attr('data-source');
    var type = $this.attr('data-target') === 'monthly' ? 'yearly' : 'monthly';

    $this.attr('href', src);
    $this.attr('data-source', url);
    $this.attr('data-target', type);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">
  <span class="monthly">Billed Monthly</span>
  <div class="custom-switch" id="undefined">
    <input class="custom-switch" type="checkbox" id="custom-switch-0">
    <label for="custom-switch-0"></label>
  </div>
  <span class="annually">Billed Annually (Save 10%) </span>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="plan__price">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/india/?amt=7499" data-source="https://www.example.com/india/?amt=6749" data-target="monthly " class="anchr btn btn-primary price-btn " target="_blank " rel="noopener "> Pay Now </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="plan__price ">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/india/?amt=7499 " data-source="https://www.example.com/india/?amt=7749" data-target="monthly" class="anchr btn btn-primary price-btn" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Pay Now</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @preranapandey Glad I could help, If this fully answers your question please accept it as an answer so other people can see you don't need help with this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'custom-switch' class targets your three buttons, you could try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.custom-switch').click(function(){
        var target = jQuery('.anchr'); // this is less wasteful
        var url = target[0].attr('href'); // notice the indices
        var src = target[0].attr('data-source');
        var type = target[0].attr('data-target');
        if(type == 'monthly'){
            target[1].attr('href', src);
            target[1].attr('data-source', url);
            target[1].attr('data-target', 'yearly');
        }else{
            target[2].attr('href', src);
            target[2].attr('data-source', url); 
            target[2].attr('data-target', 'monthly');
        }
    });
});
```